# Maas with juju - login nodes

Tags: juju, maas

I have a ubuntu server 14.04 with maas and juju, did juju bootstrap and it only bootstrapped 1 node although I have 2 nodes.

Then the default login is ubuntu for nodes, but it comes with a password and I didn't set up a password for nodes, how do I solve this issue?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3RuqPzW.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodes are set up with your user's ssh key do a `juju ssh 0` to ssh to the bootstrap node.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! Now that I'm inside of the bootstrapped node what should I do ? I deploy the services like mysql, wordpress on the MAAS server or in the bootstrapped node ? How can I add the another node in the 'Ready' state ? sorry for all this questions !

Comment: Feel free to ask them as new questions but generally you don't ssh into either the MAAS server or the bootstrap node, you deploy from your laptop/desktop.